# Using Newton's method, find correct to 4 d.p, the roots of $f(x)=sinx - \frac{1}{4}x$. Use a graph to help find an initial guess of $x_{_0}$

Tags: calculus

I was following a solution which I did not seem to understand well;

When $f(x)=sinx - \frac{1}{4}x$,

let $f'(x)=cosx - \frac{1}{4}$

Given $x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

let $x_{_0}=2$

(I assume $x_{_0}=2$ is the point of the tangent to the function (or could it be where the tangent cuts the x-axis). (I also arrive at the same answer if I use the tangent at x=3)

then approximately;

$x_1=2.6144$
$x_2=2.4793$
$x_3=2.4745$
$x_4=2.4745$

What concerns me is that the function $f(x)=sinx - \frac{1}{4}x$ has more than one root ($x=0$ and also $x=-2.4745$). Are they all valid?

Comment: Yes, they are. Note the symmetry.

Comment: Beside the symmetry, notice the trivial solution $x=0$.

Comment: Every odd function defined at $x=0$ satisfies $f(0)=0$. This follows from $f(0)=-f(0)$. And if $u$ is a root, $-u$ is a root as well because of $f(-u)=-f(u)=0$

Answer (score 0):

the other solutions are $$x\approx -2.4745767873698290126,x=0,x \approx 2.4745767873698290126$$ and see here https://www.easycalculation.com/algebra/newton-raphson-calculator.php